# Sentry - how prevent creating tokens

Tags: sentry

Tell me please,  How to prevent Sentry users from creating tokens.
Can I ban everyone in general or a specific group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug that is being fixed.
Forum link [Sentry Forum](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/discussions/35424)